Behaviour of get_parameters service for undeclared parameters differs between ROS Galactic and ROS Jazzy
I am upgrading a project from ROS Galactic to ROS Jazzy and ran into a small difference causing my code to fail. It seems that the get_parameters service returns a default initialized parameter on Galactic and returns an empty vector on Jazzy. I created a minimal example
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    MyNode() : Node("my_node")
    {
        this->declare_parameter("my_param", rclcpp::ParameterType::PARAMETER_STRING);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = std::make_shared<MyNode>();
    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

After running the node, I run:
ros2 service call /my_node/get_parameters rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters "names: ['my_param']"

I get the following response on Galactic:
response:
rcl_interfaces.srv.GetParameters_Response(values=[rcl_interfaces.msg.ParameterValue(type=0, bool_value=False, integer_value=0, double_value=0.0, string_value='', byte_array_value=[], bool_array_value=[], integer_array_value=[], double_array_value=[], string_array_value=[])])

And the following response on Jazzy:
response:
rcl_interfaces.srv.GetParameters_Response(values=[])

Is this intended? The documentation seems to indicate that a default initialized value should be returned.

I can confirm that I get the same results trying out the example in the Dockers ros:jazzy and ros:galactic.
